# I would like to dispute my post being marked as a duplicate

Tags: support, status-completed, reopen-request

I asked a question about my resume saying that I'm over-qualified but that due to illness, I'm not able to meet the requirements of jobs I've held in the past.

It didn't fit into the "how do you handle overqualified" or into the questions about illness.

I read them beforehand and edited my post to make it more clear.
Also, you will note in the comments that another poster asked why it was marked as a duplicate.

Since this has been flagged, let me explain how this is different. I do not merely have to account for being overqualified but deal with the reason being that I suffered a stroke, and the stress from continuing on the level I was on would likely trigger another one. While it is illegal to ask about medical issues, it is NOT illegal to ask about being overqualified. So this question is BOTH about being overqualified AND about having medical issues which require me to take a step back in job level.

Here is a supporting comment:

I also don't think this is a duplicate of the "overqualified" question. I'd be interested in answers, too, as I'm in a somewhat similar situation, where I simply can't work at my previous (very high) level any longer. – jamesqf 2 hours ago

[How do I address both being overqualified, and unable to perform at past levels?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/62205/how-do-i-address-both-being-overqualified-and-unable-to-perform-at-past-levels)

Comment: I think the answers to the linked question apply equally well in your case. I think the reason behind seeking a job for which you are overqualified need to be conveyed to the interviews no matter what those reasons are. And quelling any fears the interviewer might have are the key to success. All of these thoughts are contained in answers to the linked question.

Comment: I'd be happy to vote to re-open your question, but I don't think you'll get a different set of answers. VIOLA - it's done!

Comment: Thank you Joe.  I might not get any more or different answers but it's worth a shot.  Again, thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately I agree that your question is indeed a duplicate. The reasons why you'd be working at a lower level are different, but the outcome is the same: an overqualified individual seeking work at a "lower level". I sense that what you're seeking is a medical-minded approach to how to phrase why you're overqualified, at which point Worplace SE is not really the place to ask that question ...

Comment: I think you should read through the other answers. They have some good advice contained in them.

Comment: Why did you accept an answer already, if you wanted more? What do you think re-opening this question will do for you if you already think you found the answer? (confusing...)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a process in place to dispute a "duplicate" flag?](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/3508/is-there-a-process-in-place-to-dispute-a-duplicate-flag)